# Woocommerce - Customising Filter Hook

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new to WooCommerce and am trying to override the display of a template. I've copied the file over to a woocommerce folder in my theme and want to do the following:

Add a quantity box next to the Add To Card Button. Just like on the product single page.

I've tried this snippet but it only displays the Add To Cart button.

```
        <?php 
                /**
                 * woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item hook
                 *
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_loop_price - 10
                 * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
                 */ 

                 do_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item' );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is call to action. You have to add an action hook.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'callback_function' );
```

Comment: I added that but still does nothing?